# Can angles that (in radians) are irrational multiples of $\pi$ have rational sines and cosines: Niven's Theorem

Tags: number-theory

**Question amended following response from lulu.**

Am I misunderstanding Niven's Theorem? I understand it to mean that only angles $0$, $\pi/6$, and $\pi/2$ of the angles between $0$ and $\pi$ radians that are rational multiples of $\pi$ can have rational sines, but there seem to be loads of rational sines - eg $1/4$ and $5/13$ with angles $0.25268026$ and $0.39479112$ radians according to my calculator. Can angles that are irrational multiples of $\pi$ have rational trig ratios?

Thank you for your response, lulu. You are right, in that according to Niven's Theorem, the rational angles are 0,/6,/2 for rational sines. I was thinking of the cosines, which is why I originally wrote /3 instead of /6. I have now amended that. When I wrote "rational angles" I meant rational multiples of  radians. I am not so much bothered about the angles as I am about the cosines of the angles in this range and I take it from Niven's Theorem that the **cosines** must be irrational for all angles that are rational multiples of  except for 0,/3,/2. Since there are clearly many rational cosines between 0 and 1, I was asking if these are necessarily cosines of angles that are products of  and z, where z is some irrational number.

Comment: [Niven's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem), in radians, says that the only angles $0≤x≤\frac {\pi}2$ with rational sine and which are such that $\frac x{\pi}$ is also rational are $0, \frac {\pi}6, \frac {\pi}2$.

Comment: ^as a consequence of niven's theorem, yes

Comment: What I wrote is the statement of Niven's Theorem (at least in radian form).  I don't understand what you are asking about it.  (also, you write $\frac {\pi}3$ where I think you meant to  write $\frac {\pi}6$).

Answer (score 1):

It is worthwhile to understand the concept of algebraic functions vs transcendental functions.  Exponential function $e^x$,  then $\sin \pi x, \cos\pi x$ are transcendental.  There is an associated concept of exceptional sets for these functions and Niven's theorem deals with that.

The following Wikipedia article elaborates on it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function

Answer (score -1):

By the intermediate value theorem, all rationals between $-1$ and $1$ occur as values of the sine function.  Niven's theorem only talks about rational multiples of $\pi$ that have rational sines.

Furthermore, every number your calculator can display is rational, since it can only display finitely many decimal places.  Approximations are not useful in a problem like this.